# YouTube Data API: How to get private video of the other user

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

How to get private video of the other user via YouTube Data API v3?
The following page says

> "authorized requests can also retrieve information about or private to the currently authenticated user."

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

As per the developers guide you can get all users public data, but only the private of the user you are authenticating with. So no, you cannot get the private videos of another user.

Answer (score 0):

No, In order to get access to private user data your application must request consent of the user to access their data.  A random person can not access someone else private data then it wouldn't be private would it.

Public data is data this is not owned by anyone, or data which the owner has granted everyone public access. this is why you can do a video.list it shows all public videos users have uplaoded.

Private data is data that the owner has chosen to keep private.  If the owner has chosen that this video should be private then the only way to access it is by requesting their permission.

## Request access from the owner

we use [oauth2](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication) to request that consent of the user.

How that is done depends upon which programming language you are using. I recommend having a look at the current [samples](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started) on the developer sight there may be one for your language.

Once you have authorized the user you will have an access token that access token must then be sent along with the request as a authorization header

Curl just for example.

```
curl \
  'https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

Comment: How would I go about only getting private videos of a user only?